# Does Avacyn, Angel of Hope's ability continue to work even if tapped?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

[Avacyn, Angel of Hope](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Avacyn%2C%20Angel%20of%20Hope) has indestructible and gives the other creatures he controls indestructible as well. if it is tapped, are his other creatures still indestructible? Example, if he plays avacyn angel of hope and I play [Claustrophobia](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Claustrophobia) on it, am I able to kill his other creatures, or do they still have the indestructible ability?

Comment: What would lead you to believe that tapping Avacyn would change anything?

Comment: That is an important question, because there may be some other basic rules that are being misunderstood.

Comment: Claustrophobia is the Blue flavour for removal, so I can see the hope that it would serve the same function as Doom Blade. Unfortunately, not so much.

Answer (score 9):

All creatures will remain indestructible.

The only things that being tapped means is that a creature cannot attack, cannot block, and cannot tap to pay for activated abilities. Other than that, tapping has no effect.

Comment: Note that you can still pay for activated abilities that you don't need to tap for.

Answer (score 8):

Tapping has no effect on static abilities such as Avacyn's. All creatures will remain indestructible.

The ability would only work as described if it read "While Avacyn, Angel of Hope is untapped, other permanents you control have indestructible." or something similar.